# How to add space to home directory from Windows partition

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have little space in my home directory and plenty of space in my Windows partition that I don't use very much. I'm trying to move this space to my home directory.

It currently looks like that:

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           789M  1,8M  787M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        46G   40G  4,1G  91% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,9G   56M  3,8G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   16K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda7        48G   45G  806M  99% /home
/dev/sda4       324G   31G  294G  10% /media/myUser/00FABDE2FABDD3DE
/dev/sda3       107G   77G   31G  72% /media/myUser/F05C219E5C216118
```

I want to move space from `/dev/sda4` to `/dev/sda7`.

I tried using:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /dev/sda7

Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

What's the correct way?

Comment: You would have to use a partition manager to resize the partitions.  Gparted is available in the using `sudo apt install gparted`.  Run `gparted` after you install it and show a an image of your partitions.

Comment: If you edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted /dev/sda view, I can give precise instructions. Start new comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Let me know. Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Is sda4 or sda3 a bootable Windows OS? Do you also have a Windows install/repair disc?